# Phonegap Facebook Connect - Getting User's Birthday and Name

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-build

My app is in the early development stage. I'm using the latest PhoneGap Build and Facebook Connect plugin. I managed to get the login working - you tap the Login With Facebook button, it switches to the Facebook app, Facebook passes my app an object with the basic login key/token & userID, and then my app tries to reach out for the user's full name and age.

I can't seem to get Facebook to give me any information other than the user's ID and full name. I need the user's age! For some reason, adding a projection isn't working... What's wrong with my code?

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
        if(userData['status'] == 'connected'){
            getBasicUserInfo_fb(userData);
        }
    }, function(err) {
        alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
    });
}

function getBasicUserInfo_fb(userData){
    facebookConnectPlugin.api(userData['authResponse']['userID'] + "/?fields=id,birthday", ["user_birthday"], function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            alert("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(response);
            var user_name = response['name'];
            var user_age = response['birthday'];
            var user_picture = response['picture'];
        }
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

The Github page (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) says:

> **Getting a User's Birthday**
>
> Using the graph api this is a very simple task:
>
> ```
> facebookConnectPlugin.api("<user-id>/?fields=id,email", ["user_birthday"],
>     function (result) {
>         alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
>         /* alerts:
>             {
>                 "id": "000000123456789",
>                 "email": "myemail@example.com"
>             }
>         */
>     },
>     function (error) {
>         alert("Failed: " + error);
>     });
> ```

I might be losing my mind but the example on Github is saying how to get the birthday, and the scope is set up to get that, BUT then the parameters are set up to get the email address. Basically all I've done is changed "id,email" to "id,birthday"... What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was wrong to have "user_profile" in my initial login request... I guess it only accepts one parameter?

The bad version:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile","user_birthday"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
```

The good version:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["user_birthday"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
```